# How To Alter This Code So That It Only Redirects If There Is No Mouse Movement

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following JavaScript which redirects the user to another website (Google in this case):

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
window.setTimeout("location=('http://www.google.com');",5000);
</script>
```

However, although I want the website to redirect to another website, I don't want it to redirect for no reason. My aim is for the website to redirect automatically on the condition that the cursor hasn't been moved for a little while.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this should work, although on older MSIE you'd need to use their equivalent of `addEventListener()`

```
var timer = null;

function goAway() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = 'http://www.google.com/';
    }, 5000);
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', goAway, true);

goAway();  // start the first timer off
```

​All it does is ensure that every time the mouse is moved the timer is cleared, and then started up again.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/sXwHY/, although cross frame security stops it working correctly there.

Comment: one other question i have, how do i code it so that it closes the website after a certain amount of seconds?