# How to refresh page if there is no user activity for few seconds using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How To Alter This Code So That It Only Redirects If There Is No Mouse Movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825263/how-to-alter-this-code-so-that-it-only-redirects-if-there-is-no-mouse-movement)

I want to refresh a web page if there is no activity by the user using Javascript. User activity as in Key Press or mouse click.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here a basic example

```
(function(seconds) {
    var refresh,       
        intvrefresh = function() {
            clearInterval(refresh);
            refresh = setTimeout(function() {
               location.href = location.href;
            }, seconds * 1000);
        };

    $(document).on('keypress click', function() { intvrefresh() });
    intvrefresh();

}(15)); // define here seconds
```

This will refresh the page every 15 seconds without a keypress or a click event (but if you have same events defined elsewhere making a `stopPropagation()` this won't properly work because the event won't be able to reach the element)

Comment: `.triggerHandler` requires a parameter...

Comment: `.trigger` requires a parameter too ;-)

Comment: the code in the linked answer is cleaner (IMHO) because it doesn't rely on triggering a fake event to start the cycle, and also it uses capturing rather than bubbling.

Comment: ok, I could improve a little... no more fake trigger now.

Comment: yes, you could (still...)  ;-)

Comment: Thank @F.Calderan this works perfect. Also thank to Alnitak :)

Comment: If you're wanting to take it one step further in terms of "user activity", you can add 'mouseover' to the $(document).on(...). This will effectively reload the page only when the user is not browsing the page (it's about as close to "hey, I'm LOOKING at the page, don't refresh it yet" as I think you can get).

Comment: Code was not working for me with "keypress, click", needed to remove the comma so it was "keypress click".  jQuery was only handling the click event and not the keypress.

Comment: @MattSatorius thank you, just a typo that no one had noticed so far :). Updated

Answer (score 6):

Create a timer (`setTimeout`) that will refresh the page, and every time there's a key press or mouse press, just restart the timer.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825263/how-to-alter-this-code-so-that-it-only-redirects-if-there-is-no-mouse-movement) for code that does most of what you want.

FWIW, here's F.Calderan's answer rewritten to:

1. eliminate unnecessary closures
2. separate the *action* from the *repetition*, by suppling the action as a callback

--

```
function setIdle(cb, seconds) {
    var timer; 
    var interval = seconds * 1000;
    function refresh() {
            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(cb, interval);
    };
    $(document).on('keypress click', refresh);
    refresh();
}

setIdle(function() {
    location.href = location.href;
}, 15);
```