# Reload page if idle in 2 minutes

Tags: jquery

I am using idle-timer.js, and it works fine, but not with the function I would like to have:
I have just one html page with three sections: #front, #history and #items. Each section is fullscreen, and i toggle between them by giving them 'display: none;' or 'display: block;'.

I want to reload the page only if either #history or #items is idle, and I don't want the page to reload if #front is idle.

I tried different solutions, like this:

```
$.idleTimer(120000);


$(document).bind("idle.idleTimer", function() {
    if ($(‘#items’).css(‘display’) === ‘block’ || (‘#history’).css(‘display’) === ‘block’)) {
        location.reload();
    }   
});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [How To Alter This Code So That It Only Redirects If There Is No Mouse Movement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825263/how-to-alter-this-code-so-that-it-only-redirects-if-there-is-no-mouse-movement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong quotes (backtick), and missing the `$` character in the `#history` selector:

```
if ($('#items').is(':visible') || $('#history').is(':visible')) {
    location.reload();
}
```

Comment: Also OP is using \`(backtick) instead of quotes. I'd suggest you to use `is(':visible')` to check if the element is visible, `display` can have different values(ex. `inline`), not always `block`

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

try it and let me know if it works

```
var timer = 0 ;

$(document).on("mousemove",function()
{
    timer = 0;
});

setInterval(function()
{
     if(timer >= 120000)
        location.reload();
     else
        timer +=1000;

     if(!$("#history").is(":visible") && !$("#items").is(":visible"))
        timer=0;
},1000);
```

Comment: This does not adress OPs issues, there isn't any check for what page the user is currently at.